# SQL Edits first option only

Tags: php, mysql

This is the code from our handle page we are trying to edit our database in phpmyadmin but can seem to only edit our first entry even though we clicked on other entries' edit button

```
require 'dbfunction.php';
$con = getDbConnect();
$crew_id = $_POST["crew_id"];
$CrewName = $_POST["CrewName"];
$CrewRank = $_POST["CrewRank"];
$StartDate = $_POST["StartDate"];
$EndDate = $_POST["EndDate"];
$PayrollNo = $_POST["PayrollNo"];
$EmployeeNo = $_POST["EmployeeNo"];
$WatchKeeping = $_POST["WatchKeeping"];
$Active = $_POST["Active"];
//$Delete = $_POST["Delete"];

if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

$queryStr = "SELECT crew_id " .
        "FROM crewlist";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    $sqlQueryStr = "UPDATE crewlist SET crew_name = '$CrewName', crew_rank = '$CrewRank', start_date = '$StartDate' "
            . ", end_date = '$EndDate', payroll_no = '$PayrollNo'"
            . ", employee_no = '$EmployeeNo', watchkeeping = '$WatchKeeping', active = '$Active' WHERE crew_id = " . $row['crew_id'];

    mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);

    mysqli_close($con);
} else {
    break;
}
header('Location: crewlisting.php');
}

?>
```

This code only edits the first entry of our database and the rest remains stagnant. This is the code from our edit page

```
<?php
            if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

                $queryStr = "SELECT * " .
                        "FROM crewlist";
            }
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                echo "<tr>.<th>" . $row["crew_name"] . "<br></br>" . "</th>";
                echo "<th>" . $row["crew_rank"] . "</th>";
                echo "<th>" . $row["start_date"] . "</th>";
                echo "<th>" . $row["end_date"] . "</th>";
                echo "<th>" . $row["watchkeeping"] . "</th>";
                echo "<th>" . $row["active"] . "</th>";
                //echo "<td><form action=\"editcrew.php\" method=\"post\"><a href='editcrew.php?del={$row['crew_id']}'>edit</a></form></td>";
                echo "<td><a href=\"editcrew.php?id=" . $row['crew_id'] . "\">Edit</a>";
               echo "<td><form action=\"delete.php\" method=\"post\"><a href='crewlisting.php?del={$row['crew_id']}'>delete</a></form></td>";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Btw, never execute a query inside a loop (unless it's some kind of procedural mathematics ). And see about mysqli's prepared statement syntax

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your mysqli connection in the first iteration of your loop. Move the `mysqli_close($con);` behind the loop.

Edit: And you also redirect to crewlist.php in the loop. If you reformat your indentation of your code, this will get obvious.

Comment: It used to be outside but we edited all entries at once from 1 click

Answer (score 0):

Remove `mysqli_close($con)` from loop:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sqlQueryStr = "UPDATE crewlist SET crew_name = '$CrewName', crew_rank = '$CrewRank', start_date = '$StartDate' "
            . ", end_date = '$EndDate', payroll_no = '$PayrollNo'"
            . ", employee_no = '$EmployeeNo', watchkeeping = '$WatchKeeping', active = '$Active' WHERE crew_id = " . $row['crew_id'];

    mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);

}
header('Location: crewlisting.php');
```